# Dynamically Creating WebView From C++ Through JNI

Tags: c++, android, java-native-interface, webview

In my C++ code, I create an instance of a Java class through JNI. That Java class's job is to create a WebView dynamically that should go on top of the application's views.

My current strategy is to retrieve the application's main activity, dynamically create a WebView and attach it to the main activity's list of views. Is this possible? Is it better to create an activity?

This functionality is meant for a standalone library that clients can use. So unfortunately it can't be part of the main application's activity.

At minimum, is it possible to retrieve the application's main activity from an unrelated Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, my Java class has a static method Init that is called by my activity to store the reference to the activity. Later, when my C++ code creates an instance of the Java class it retrieves that reference and uses it.